# Передать матрицу в шейдер

Tags: android, libgdx, шейдеры

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, я использую инстансинг меша, и хочу передать матрицу в шейдер, чтобы можно было любой из экземпляров повернуть или заскейлить, передать координаты позиции могу, но, хотел бы матрицу, подскажите, как правильно это сделать ?
Спасибо

Comment: Во-первых, в opengl es 2.0 работа с инстансингом возможно только при наличии соответсвующих расширений. Во-вторых, если количество экземпляров не очень много, то массив трансформов надо передать в шейдер, а их уже достовать по id через gl_InstanceIDEXT.

Comment: @MasterFlomaster я использую opengl es 3.0

Comment: ну тогда просто используй gl_InstanceID

Answer (score 0):

Матрицы обычно передаются в юниформы. В шейдере пишите в списке получаемых атрибутов юниформу

```
uniform mat4 u_Matrix;
```

Потом в программе перед драуколами устанавливаете значение. В libgdx вроде как-то так это делается

```
float[] matrix = new float[16];
program.setUniformf("u_Matrix", matrix_array);
```

Если не работали с юниформами, почитайте что это. В целом это что-то вроде статических переменных, один раз положили, в любом месте шейдера используете

Comment: но ведь при инстансинге все объекты получат одну и ту же юниформу..

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ,да, вы можете подсказать как передать правильно матрицу?

Comment: `program.enableVertexAttribute ("transform");
program.getAttributeLocation ("transform")
meshInstanced.get (a) .enableInstancedRendering (true, Tree,
                         new VertexAttribute (attributeLocation, 4, "transform"),
                         new VertexAttribute (attributeLocation + 1, 4, "transform"),
                         new VertexAttribute (attributeLocation + 2, 4, "transform"),
                         new VertexAttribute (attributeLocation + 3, 4, "transform"));`

Пытался так, но, не работает

Comment: никогда не писал под андроид, и не использовал инстансинг, однако читал теорию, вот нагуглил какой то туториал, беглый просмотр показал что тут mvp матрицу передают через vbo https://ahbejarano.gitbook.io/lwjglgamedev/chapter21

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо большое, буду разбираться